# Can I mount a Docker image as a volume in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I would like to distribute some larger static files/assets as a Docker image so that it is easy for user to pull those optional files down the same way they would be pulling the app itself. But I cannot really find a good way to expose files from one Docker image to the other? Is there a way to mount a Docker image itself (or a directory in it) as a volume to other Docker container?

I know that there are volume plugins I could use, but I could not find any where I could to this or something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is possible create **any directory of an image** to a docker volume, but **not full image**. At least not in a pretty or simple way.

If you want to create a directory from your image as a docker volume you can create a named volume:

```
docker volume create your_volume
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name=yourcontainer \
  -v your_volume:/dir_with_data_you_need \
  your_docker_image
```

From this point, you'll have accessible `your_volume` with data from image `your_docker_image`

Reason why you cannot mount the whole image in a volume is because docker doesn't let specify `/` as source of named volume. You'll get `Cannot create container for service your-srv: invalid volume spec "/": invalid volume specification: '/'` even if you try with docker-compose.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Because to me Docker mounts an empty volume over data in `/dir_with_data_you_need` so you do not really get access to files in the image.

Comment: Or maybe this really works. There is a difference between bind and non-bind volumes.

Comment: This really works. If you mount an non-bind volume on top of a directory inside the image, contents of that directory are copied into the volume. For me the issue is that copying means unnecessary double disk space usage.

Comment: For me, I just end up with an empty directory on both sides...

Comment: This won't work. It will copy data from `/dir_with_data_you_need` into the volume, but it will do it only once. If you change the image (eg. to update the contents to next version) the new version will not be copied.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know any direct way.

You can use a folder in your host as a bridge to share things, this is a indirect way to acheive this.

```
docker run -d -v /any_of_your_host_folder:/your_assets_folder_in_your_image_container your_image
docker run -d -v /any_of_your_host_folder:/your_folder_of_your_new_container your_container_want_to_use_assets
```

For your_image, you need add CMD in dockerfile to copy the assets to your_assets_folder_in_your_image_container(the one you use as volume as CMD executes after volume)

This may waste time, but just at the first time the assets container starts. And after the container starts, the files in assets container in fact copy to the host folder, and has none business with assets image any more. So you can just delete the image of the assets image. Then no space waste.

You aim just want other people easy to use the assets, so why not afford script to them, automatically fetch the image -> start the container(CMD auto copy files to volume) -> delete the image/container -> the assets already on host, so people just use this host assets as a volume to do next things.

Of course, if container can directly use other image's resource, it is better than this solution. Anyway, this can be a solution although not perfect.

Comment: Files are in the image, so mapping a volume will not work. I would have to then inside the files container copy all the files into the volume, which would waste space.

Comment: Yes, you are right. We had to set up a internal folder & copy assets to it in assets image's `CMD`. It really waste space, depends your assets' size. But if a lot of container need to use this assets, this could be a solution. I don't know if docker could directly handle a layer with aufs or overlay with specify another image, maybe could investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the docker sock as a volume which will allow you to start one of your docker images from within your docker container.

To do this, add the two following volumes:

```
- "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
- "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker"
```

If you need to share files between the containers map the volume `/tmp:/tmp` when starting both containers.

Comment: Files are in the image, so mapping a volume will not work. I would have to then inside the files container copy all the files into the volume, which would waste space.