# Restore data after dockerfile update

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm developing in a docker container via VSCode using WSL via Rancher Desktop.  The Dockerfile was originally pulling from node:alpine but when I updated it to pull from node:bookworm (Debian based), all of my development was erased.  I had previously updated the Dockerfile without issue, but never the base image.

I've run `docker image ls` and got a large list of images (which I assume means an image was created everytime I made a change to the Dockerfile), with one anonymous image having been created when I made the problematic Dockerfile update and the previous one created much farther back. Also, both the volume and the container are the same, at least in name.  So far I've tried mounting the older image in the volume ([Can I mount a Docker image as a volume in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428168/can-i-mount-a-docker-image-as-a-volume-in-docker)), and restarting rancher/WSL but neither resolved the issue.